# Log file in Crashlytics

Tags: crashlytics

Where can I find the Logs/uncaught exceptions messages that are thrown by CrashLytics ? I would like to see them in a .txt file, for instance instead of the dashboard.

Comment: Hey Oscar,

Mike from Fabric here. 

You can download any of the custom logs from a crash in a .log file from your Crashlytics dashboard so that you can view that anywhere you want. Great to know you'd like to see this for an uncaught exception as well, but you can copy out the raw stack trace wherever you want.

Comment: Hello Mike. Thanks for the answer. I can not find "the custom logs from a crash in a .log file from your Crashlytics dashboard". I am trying to find in right in the Dashboard but I can not find it, would you help me a bit?

Comment: Sure Oscar, I think I replied to your email via support, but if I'm confused, just drop me a note at support(at)fabric(dot)io

Comment: did you find on where to get the custom logs from craslytics web dashboard

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE** This is no more used as fabric crashlytics is deprecated and is replaced with firebase crashlytics [refer this doc to use firebase crashlytic logs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=android#log_is_now_an_instance_method)

Make sure you've logged the data using `Crashlytics.log(int priority, String tag, String msg);` before the crash happens.

On the Fabric dashboard, select an Issue, then from the  **Issue Details** page, click on **View all sessions** button. [image: View all sessions]

This will lead you to the specific crash details where you'll find the logs you logged before the crash. Per the documentation, the logs are a rolling 64kb FIFO buffered log.

[image: Image of logs]